# Flex launching pdf/doc file which is downloaded as ByteArray

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, arrays

I want to open a pdf/excel/doc using flex, as all know we can use navigateToUrl(URL) method to open a file from the server. But my problem is those files are encrypted in the server, so I load the files as follows

```
ByteLoader = new URLLoader();
ByteLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
ByteLoader.load(new URLRequest (constructedURL));
```

so that I can manipulate them and can get the decrypted file. Now my question is, my data already got downloaded from the server, so how will I launch the files(pdf/doc/excel) with the binary content which I had got?

Is there anyway i can launch those files like we do it in navigateToURL()?

Comment: Is it AIR application or Browser integrated swf ?

Comment: Hi Yordan,It is browser based not an AIR app. thanks, Mani

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer, this is many times the case but I can offer one fall-back solution you can use the [FileReference save method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29) (believe this is Flash Player 10 and above).  The problem then becomes opening the locally saved file, since based on the documentation the name is populated only by the browse or download methods but not save you may not be able to use the name (furthermore I believe this is only the name of the file not including the full native path it was saved to, however this would probably be worth exploring).  If you were in some way able to obtain the native path the file was saved to I would imagine you could use a navigateToURL(new URLRequest("file:///")) to get it to open the local file, I tried out this last part with a file I already had saved on my hard drive and it worked:

```
        var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
        fr.save("something worth saving", "somefile.txt");
        fr.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, function(event:Event):void
        {
            trace("something selected: " + event.target.name);
        });

        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("file:///C:/tmp0001-0160.avi"));
```

Basically though it looks like to make this actually work you'd need to have a guarantee that you know where the user is going to save the file, probably better off to just have them save it and open it themselves unless someone can offer a better solution.